# Java audio recording noise in completely quite room

Tags: java, audio, javasound, recording

I'm trying audio recording with java. And the quality is not good at all. There is a continuous noise, even though it is completely quite here in the room. Any chance to remove/filter the noise?

I've discovered the same issue on cheap android phone and some recording app. Looks like it is general issue with audio recording

```
package test;

import javax.sound.sampled.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Tmp {

    AudioFileFormat.Type fileType = AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE;


    AudioFormat getAudioFormat() {
        float sampleRate = 44100;
        int sampleSizeInBits = 16;
        int channels = 1;
        boolean signed = true;
        boolean bigEndian = true;
        AudioFormat format = new AudioFormat(sampleRate, sampleSizeInBits,
                                             channels, signed, bigEndian);
        return format;
    }

    void start(String n) {
        TargetDataLine line;
        File f = new File(n);
        try {
            AudioFormat format = getAudioFormat();
            DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(TargetDataLine.class, format);
            line = (TargetDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
            line.open(format);
            line.start();
            AudioInputStream ais = new AudioInputStream(line);
            AudioSystem.write(ais, fileType, f);

        } catch (LineUnavailableException | IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: *"in completely quite room"*  You have a perfect anechoic chamber?

Comment: No. But there are no every day life sounds, like speech, music, cars, etc

Comment: 16-bit stereo at 44100 fps is CD quality. The weak link is not Java. More likely it is your microphones or speakers. But looking at your specs, I'm wondering about the use of BigEndian. Are you on a Mac? I don't know about Android. For my PC, the wav file format that works best is LittleEndian. Maybe it is worth trying to switch to BigEndian = false. It's an easy experiment.

Comment: BigEndian setting seems to have no effect. At least I cannot hear any difference in quality. I think, it is just bad mic quality. I wonder if the noise can be suppressed somehow

Comment: I'm having exactly the same issue and this has nothing to do with the mic.